# Playing a music playlist as an alarm?

Tags: music, music-player, alarm

How to have an alarm that will start playing selections from a playlist at the scheduled time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gentle Alarm. Seems a little complex at first with profiles and alarms, but it rocks. The best feature is the one that allows you to skip alarms set to go off without actually turning off a configured alarm. I use that feature all the time. You have to pay for it, but its worth it.

There was a comment about the concern of Gentle Alarm's Internet usage, [below is what I found on the dev's forum](http://m.mobitobi.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=818):

> I need internet access to allow users
>   to send me information if they choose
>   so. Unfortunately, there are no
>   conditional permissions. So even if
>   you always decide not to send me any
>   information when a crash happens, I
>   still need the permission.
>
> There are two more reasons for
>   Internet permission:
>
> - If you paid via Paypal, you have to enter a key to unlock the app. This
>     key is checked at some point when you
>     are online every 3 months.
> - And for market users such as system is coming. Google recently added a
>     licensing scheme as a minor step
>     against piracy and you will start
>     seeing this used in more and more
>     apps. The app needs to call Google
>     servers to check if the license is
>     valid. Results are cached so that the
>     app also works if online for extended
>     periods of time.
>
> The latter two reasons are
>   unfortunate. But for every legal copy
>   I sell, there are more than 3 illegal
>   ones out there. There are even some
>   people who bundle apps and sell them
>   at a discount. Piracy has gone out of
>   hand and if developers don't earn
>   money with their apps, there will be
>   fewer quality apps in the future.
>
> I will gladly discuss any concerns you
>   may have.

Answer (score 6):

Alarm Clock Plus V2. Its free in the app market. Let's you set a song or a playlist, plus it has a ton of other options. Its really a killer app.

**Update:** I still have the free ad supported version Alarm Clock Plus installed on my phone but it looks like it's gone from the market.  [The only one left is the paid, ad-free version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vp.alarmClockPlusV2).

Comment: Any chance you could add a link to the app.  Searching for Alarm Clock Plus V2 didn't return an app with that name.

Comment: It looks like the free version is gone from the market.

Answer (score 2):

[Good Morning](http://www.appbrain.com/app/good-morning/com.flywheelsoft.goodmorning) will let you "shuffle from a directory" of your choice. The app is free. It will also announce the day's date and forecast for the day, as well as assign the alarm to specific days of the week.

Answer (score 0):

[Tone Picker (AppBrain link)](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.hlidskialf.android.tonepicker) will allow you to use sound files for ringtones, notifications, or alarm sounds.

I use the standard Alarm clock on my HTC Incredible (not sure if it's stock Android, or Sense), but I've got MP3s for some of the alrams. Same too for some of the rings.

UPDATE: re-read the OP. Not from a playlist.

Answer (score 0):

[Alarmdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.splunchy.android.alarmclock) is also great!
It supports custom playlists and even internet radio.

> Android «flip'n'snooze» Alarm Clock Application. Makes you wake up in your way!
>
> AlarmDroid is a feature-rich alarm clock application. It is created to give every Android-User the opportunity to wake up his(her) own way, not caring about whether he(she) is an early bird or a morning grouch.
>   AlarmDroid's special feature is the flip'n'snooze feature, which allows the user to turn the alarm clock back into snooze mode by turning over the phone. Further, it provides a speaking clock, which does not only announce the time but even the local weather conditions.
>   These and more features are waiting to be discovered by you! Even internet radio stations are supported as alarm tone.

Comment: This one still works and is free (+1)